# Why is the pointer in this nested class missing?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, nested, operator-overloading

**Question in short:**

class B has a ptr to class C, which has a class D having a ptr to class B

assign class B to an array in class A by copying, expecting to see to ptr points to new instance in the array not original instance, but failed.

I am already able to do some workaround, but I want to know why my original approach fails.

***More detailed explainations are as follows, and the code to reproduce the problem is posted as well***

Anyone who is able to explain what is going on is appreciated.

**There are 6 classes:**

class CastInfo //contains a Character*

class Skill  //abstract class, contains CastInfo

class Movvement : public Skill

class Move1 : public Movement

class Character //contains a Movement*, which will be Move1* in practice

class Squad //contains an array of Character

**with the following relationships:**

1. Character* in CastInfo should point to the Character who owns the Skill which 
   is the owner of CastInfo
2. when assigning the Skill to Character, the Character* in CastInfo points to that Character
3. the Character in Squad's array should be copied, so there will be 2 instances and the Character* in CastInfo should also point to Character in Squad's array not original instance

**The expecting result is:**

1. move1 != ch1.move1 != squad.ch[0].move1 (this is already satisfied)
2. ch1.move1->cast_info.caster == &ch1 != squad.ch[0].move1->caster_info.caster (this is the problem)

**There are 2 cases (tried) of the output:**

In the Squad's constructor,:
if using

```
characters_[i] = characters[i];
```

the character is correctly copied, but the skill is at same address

```
move1: 00000270E6093500
ch1: 000000BC6DCFF378
ch1.move1: 00000270E6093E60
ch1.move1->cast_info.caster: 000000BC6DCFF378
squad.ch[0]: 000000BC6DCFF3E0
squad.ch[0].move1: 00000270E6093E60
squad.ch[0].move1->cast_info.caster: 000000BC6DCFF378
```

if using

```
characters_[i] = Character(characters[i]);
```

the character is correctly copied, but the skill is missing (pointing to some weird location)

```
move1: 00000230FDCEF080
ch1: 00000058A11DF548
ch1.move1: 00000230FDCEF260
ch1.move1->cast_info.caster: 00000058A11DF548
squad.ch[0]: 00000058A11DF5B0
squad.ch[0].move1: 00000230FDCEF0E0
squad.ch[0].move1->cast_info.caster: 00000058A11DF378
```

In the first case, I guess it is probably because I did not overload operator=, so only address is copied. I tried to overload it but it caused more problem. (Such as when using Builder.Build() )

In the second case, I expect it first call copy constructor, which triggers SetMove1(), which calls SetCaster(). move1 is cloned as shown, but I cannot understand why caster is not updated correctly. (Though is calls operator= after construnction, the address should remain the same.)

**The following code should reproduce the problem:**

motion.h

```
#pragma once
class Character;

struct CastInfo
{
    Character* caster;
    int coeff;
};

class Skill
{
public:
    CastInfo cast_info;
    Skill() {};
    ~Skill() {};
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Movement : public Skill
{
public:
    Movement();
    ~Movement();
    virtual void DoSomething() { ; }
    virtual Movement* Clone() const { return new Movement(*this); }
};

class Move1 : public Movement
{
public:
    Move1() { cast_info.coeff = 123; }
    void DoSomething() { ; }
    virtual Move1* Clone() const { return new Move1(*this); }
};

class Move2 : public Movement
{
public:
    void DoSomething() { ; }
};
```

motion.cpp:

```
#include "motion.h"
Movement::Movement() { }
Movement::~Movement() { }
```

test.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "motion.h"
#define SQUAD_SIZE 6

extern Movement* null_movement;
class Character
{
public:
    class Builder;
    Character();
    ~Character();
    Character(const Character& character);
    Character& SetMove1(Movement* skill);
public:
    int id_;
    Movement* move1_ = null_movement;
    Movement* move2_ = null_movement;
    Character(int id) : id_(id) { ; }
    void SetCaster();
};

class Character::Builder : public Character
{
public:
    Builder& SetId(int i) { id_ = i; return *this; }
    Character Build() { return Character(id_); }
};

class Squad
{
public: 
    class Builder;
    Squad() { }
    Squad(const Squad& squad);
    ~Squad() { }
public:
    Character characters_[SQUAD_SIZE];
    Squad(Character* characters);
};

class Squad::Builder :public Squad
{
public:
    Builder& SetCharacter(const Character& character, const int position) { characters_[position] = character; return *this; }
    Squad Build() { return Squad(characters_); }
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

Movement* null_movement = new Move2();
Character::Character() : id_(0) { }
Character::~Character() {}
Character::Character(const Character& character) {
    id_ = character.id_;
    SetMove1(character.move1_);
}

Character& Character::SetMove1(Movement* move1) {
    if (!move1) return *this;
    move1_ = move1->Clone(); 
    SetCaster();
    return *this;
}

void Character::SetCaster() { 
    if (move1_ != NULL) move1_->cast_info.caster = this;
}

Squad::Squad(const Squad& squad) {
    *this = squad;
}

Squad::Squad(Character* characters) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SQUAD_SIZE; i++) {
        //characters_[i] = characters[i];  //character copied, skill same address
        characters_[i] = Character(characters[i]); //character copied, skill missing
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
#include "motion.h"
int main() {

    Move1* move1 = new Move1();
    std::cout << "move1: " << move1 << std::endl;

    Character ch1 = Character::Builder().SetId(1).Build();
    Character ch2 = Character::Builder().SetId(2).Build();
    ch1.SetMove1(move1);

    std::cout << "ch1: " << &ch1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ch1.move1: " << (ch1.move1_) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ch1.move1->cast_info.caster: " << (ch1.move1_->cast_info.caster) << std::endl;

    Squad squad = Squad::Builder().SetCharacter(ch1, 0).SetCharacter(ch2, 1).Build();

    std::cout << "squad.ch[0]: " << &(squad.characters_[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "squad.ch[0].move1: " << (squad.characters_[0].move1_) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "squad.ch[0].move1->cast_info.caster: " << (squad.characters_[0].move1_->cast_info.caster) << std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**As previously mentioned, I have a workaround to reach my goal:**

By creating another method, which iterates through the array in Squad, and call each Character's SetCaster() method.

```
void Squad::SetCaster() {
    for (int i = 0; i < SQUAD_SIZE; i++) {
        characters_[i].SetCaster();
    }
}
```

But I think this is dirty because every time after Builder::Builder(), SetCaster() must be called, which is unintuitive and error-prone.

Comment: Any chance you could whittle it down into something a bit more manageable that still demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Serously: `Character ch1 = Character::Builder().SetId(1).Build();` That is supposed to be easier to read than `Character ch1(1);`

Comment: `copy constructor, which triggers SetMove1()`. Copy constructors can be elided if the compiler thinks it can do an optimization (even if the copy constuctor has side affects (which it should not)).

Comment: @Steve I believe all of the members and methods listed here are used, except class Skill and class Move2, which are shown to express how the Skill system looks like.

Comment: @LokiAstari Really? I do not know there is a chance that compiler can pass it. However, in this case it seems not passed because I set a breakpoint in copy constructor and it is working. Is there any keyword to learn more about this?

Comment: And yes, the build pattern is great. Especially for a class such as Character, which usually has dozens of members.

Comment: @adayoegi That is only true if the dozens of parameters all have default values (and thus you only set a subset of them). If you are creating random characters that no longer holds and thus a simple constructor is better.

Comment: @LokiAstari I see. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, as illustrated below:

The problem is in

```
Squad::Squad(Character* characters) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SQUAD_SIZE; i++) {
        //characters_[i] = characters[i];  //character copied, skill same address
        characters_[i] = Character(characters[i]); //character copied, skill missing
    }
}
```

As mentioned in question, using the commented line is just copying the values, which is incorrect.

What

```
characters_[i] = Character(characters[i]); //character copied, skill missing
```

does is as follows:

1. create a Character, by calling Character's constructer, this object is at address A. SetMove1() is called, SetCaster() is called. The pointer in cast_info is pointing at A correctly.
2. assign the object to characters_[i], **whose address is at address B because the address of characters_ is assigned when Squad is created**. As I did not overload Character::operator=, the pointer is still pointing to **address A**
3. Constructor done, Squad returned.

This is the reason

```
std::cout << "squad.ch[0].move1->cast_info.caster: " << (squad.characters_[0].move1_->cast_info.caster) << std::endl;
```

shows a third address (address A) which is neither &(character[0]) (address B) nor &ch1 (original character's address)

The solution is either to overload operator= or put my "workaround" (Squad::SetCaster()) in constructor right after the for loop.

Please correct me if there is anything wrong, or if there is any better solution.

Comment: BTW, overloading operator= seems to do exactly the same thing as copy constructor. Is there any way that can avoid duplicating the code twice? Calling one in another seems to be a mess.